# getent passwd output as json in correct format

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, format

I'm using jq in order to try converting bash command output to json. However, the conversion fails me.

Using this line:

```
hostname && getent passwd | egrep -v '/s?bin/(nologin|shutdown|sync|halt)' | cut -d: -f1 | sudo xargs -I % sh -c  'echo %; chage -l %; echo' | jq --raw-input . | jq --slurp .
```

- Hostname must be root element of the json
- Username must be first element
- getent passwd output must be sub elements of username

Something like this:
[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QaVr.jpg)

Outputof above command without use of jq results in:
[Command Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E69k0.jpg)

Anybody ever tried converting bash output to json correctly? Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the output of `hostname && getent passwd | egrep -v '/s?bin/(nologin|shutdown|sync|halt)' | cut -d: -f1 | sudo xargs -I % sh -c  'echo %; chage -l %; echo'` (passwords masked)?

Comment: sure. output is now added above.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using jq...

I realize `jq` is popular around here, but I'm going to recommend [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) for this task.
Although primarily a HTML/XML/JSON parser (using CSS, XPath, XQuery, JSONiq and pattern templates), Xidel can also process basic text.

You say you'd like to have a json like this one:

```json
{
  "hostname": "example",
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "example1",
      "details": {
        "LastPasswordChange": "Nov 12, 2018",
        "PasswordExpires": "never",
        "PasswordInactive": "never",
        "AccountExpires": "never",
        "MinDaysBetweenPasswordChange": "0",
        "MaxDaysBetweenPasswordChange": "99999",
        "NumOfDaysOfWarningBeforePasswordExpires": "7"
      }
    },
    {
      "username": "example2",
      "details": {
        "LastPasswordChange": "Nov 13, 2018",
        "PasswordExpires": "never",
        "PasswordInactive": "never",
        "AccountExpires": "never",
        "MinDaysBetweenPasswordChange": "0",
        "MaxDaysBetweenPasswordChange": "99999",
        "NumOfDaysOfWarningBeforePasswordExpires": "7"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That means the `users` array needs to be filled with objects (created from this `chage` program's output) for every user **separately**. This is why I'd choose another approach.

Let's say `getent passwd | egrep -v '/s?bin/(nologin|shutdown|sync|halt)' | cut -d: -f1` returns:

```
root
user1
user2
```

This we're going to pipe to Xidel to first create a basic json:

```
getent passwd | egrep -v '/s?bin/(nologin|shutdown|sync|halt)' | cut -d: -f1 | xidel -s - --xquery '
  {
    "hostname":"'$(hostname)'",
    "users":x:lines($raw) ! {
      "username":.
    }
  }
'
```

- There's no need for `hostname &&` in front of your original command, because you simply call it from within Xidel (which also makes the query much easier).
- With `x:lines($raw)` you create a sequence of every new line from Xidel's input (stdin in this case). An alternative function to use would be `tokenize($raw,"\n")`.

The query output:

```
{
  "hostname": "user",
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "root"
    },
    {
      "username": "user1"
    },
    {
      "username": "user2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Next we're going to call `chage` from within Xidel to create the `details` object:

```
getent passwd | egrep -v '/s?bin/(nologin|shutdown|sync|halt)' | cut -d: -f1 | xidel -s - --xquery '
  {
    "hostname":"'$(hostname)'",
    "users":x:lines($raw) ! {
      "username":.,
      "details":{|
        for $x in x:lines(
          system(x"chage -l {.}")
        )
        let $a:=tokenize(
          $x,
          ":"
        )
        return {
          normalize-space($a[1]):normalize-space($a[2])
        }
      |}
    }
  }
'
```

- `system(x"chage -l {.}")` returns the output of `chage -l root`, `chage -l user1` and `chage -l user2`.
- With `x:lines()` around it you again create a sequence of every new line. The first line for `user2`'s output for instance:

```
Last password change                                  : Oct 23, 2018
```

- For every item in this sequence (or line) the variable `$a` is created, which holds a sequence of this item split in two, with `:` as the delimiter. `$a` thus for this first item:

```
Last password change                                  # white-space up untill this point! 
 Oct 23, 2018
```

- Finally the attribute-value pair is created, with white-space normalized:

```
{
  "Last password change": "Oct 23, 2018"
}
```

The query output:

```
{
  "hostname": "user",
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "root",
      "details": {
        "Last password change": "never",
        "Password expires": "never",
        "Password inactive": "never",
        "Account expires": "never",
        "Minimum number of days between password change": "0",
        "Maximum number of days between password change": "99999",
        "Number of days of warning before password expires": "7"
      }
    },
    {
      "username": "user1",
      "details": {
        "Last password change": "never",
        "Password expires": "never",
        "Password inactive": "never",
        "Account expires": "never",
        "Minimum number of days between password change": "0",
        "Maximum number of days between password change": "99999",
        "Number of days of warning before password expires": "7"
      }
    },
    {
      "username": "user2",
      "details": {
        "Last password change": "Oct 23, 2018",
        "Password expires": "never",
        "Password inactive": "never",
        "Account expires": "never",
        "Minimum number of days between password change": "0",
        "Maximum number of days between password change": "99999",
        "Number of days of warning before password expires": "7"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You could go one step further:

```
getent passwd | egrep -v '/s?bin/(nologin|shutdown|sync|halt)' | cut -d: -f1 | xidel -s - --xquery '
  {
    "hostname":"'$(hostname)'",
    "users":x:lines($raw) ! {
      "username":.,
      "details":{|
        for $x in x:lines(
          system(x"chage -l {.}")
        )
        let $a:=tokenize(
          $x,
          ":"
        )
        return {
          string-join(
            for $x in tokenize(
              normalize-space($a[1]),
              " "
            )
            return
            upper-case(
              substring(
                $x,
                1,
                1
              )
            )||substring(
              $x,
              2
            )
          ):normalize-space($a[2]) ! (
            if (. castable as decimal) then
              number(.)
            else
              .
          )
        }
      |}
    }
  }
'
```

- Instead of `Last password change`, with...

```
string-join(for $x in tokenize(normalize-space($a[1])," ") return upper-case(substring($x,1,1))||substring($x,2))
```

...it returns: `LastPasswordChange`.

- Instead of `"99999"` (a string), with...

```
normalize-space($a[2]) ! (if (. castable as decimal) then number(.) else .)
```

...it returns: `99999` as xs:decimal atomic type.

The query output:

```
{
  "hostname": "user",
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "root",
      "details": {
        "LastPasswordChange": "never",
        "PasswordExpires": "never",
        "PasswordInactive": "never",
        "AccountExpires": "never",
        "MinimumNumberOfDaysBetweenPasswordChange": 0,
        "MaximumNumberOfDaysBetweenPasswordChange": 99999,
        "NumberOfDaysOfWarningBeforePasswordExpires": 7
      }
    },
    {
      "username": "user1",
      "details": {
        "LastPasswordChange": "never",
        "PasswordExpires": "never",
        "PasswordInactive": "never",
        "AccountExpires": "never",
        "MinimumNumberOfDaysBetweenPasswordChange": 0,
        "MaximumNumberOfDaysBetweenPasswordChange": 99999,
        "NumberOfDaysOfWarningBeforePasswordExpires": 7
      }
    },
    {
      "username": "user2",
      "details": {
        "LastPasswordChange": "Oct 23, 2018",
        "PasswordExpires": "never",
        "PasswordInactive": "never",
        "AccountExpires": "never",
        "MinimumNumberOfDaysBetweenPasswordChange": 0,
        "MaximumNumberOfDaysBetweenPasswordChange": 99999,
        "NumberOfDaysOfWarningBeforePasswordExpires": 7
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

A "prettified" query is much easier to read, but if you prefer the "minified" version:

```
getent passwd | egrep -v '/s?bin/(nologin|shutdown|sync|halt)' | cut -d: -f1 | xidel -s - --xquery '{"hostname":"'$(hostname)'","users":x:lines($raw) ! {"username":.,"details":{|for $x in x:lines(system(x"chage -l {.}")) let $a:=tokenize($x,":") return {string-join(for $x in tokenize(normalize-space($a[1])," ") return upper-case(substring($x,1,1))||substring($x,2)):normalize-space($a[2]) ! (if (. castable as decimal) then number(.) else .)}|}}}'
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Much appreciated! Having trouble figuring out how to install xidel, but I will manage I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl script that displays the hostname and contents of `/etc/passwd` in JSON format (The output doesn't look anything your example on any OS I'm familiar with, btw.)

Note that of course 'first element' makes no sense when talking about keys of a JSON object; they're unordered. If you depend on a particular key being at particular place in an object, you're doing it wrong.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Sys::Hostname;
use User::pwent;
# Might have to install through your OS's package manager or
# with your favorite CPAN client
use JSON;

my %pwdb = ( hostname => hostname(), users => [] );

while (my $pw = getpwent) {
  # Ignore users with certain shells
  next if
    defined $pw->shell && $pw->shell =~ m!s?bin/(nologin|shutdown|sync|halt)!;
  push @{$pwdb{"users"}}, {
                           username => $pw->name,
                           details => {
                                       passwd => $pw->passwd,
                                       uid => $pw->uid,
                                       gid => $pw->gid,
                                       change => $pw->change,
                                       age => $pw->age,
                                       quota => $pw->quota,
                                       comment => $pw->comment,
                                       class => $pw->class,
                                       gecos => $pw->gecos,
                                       dir => $pw->dir,
                                       shell => $pw->shell,
                                       expire => $pw->expire
                                      }
                          };
}

my $pp = JSON->new->ascii->pretty;
print $pp->encode(\%pwdb);
```

Comment: Okay, I see where your desired output is coming from; This chage program, not the passwd database. You really should be clearer about that in your question. I'll update my answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the command somewhere and not very good at bash yet. Thats why i couldn't be clearer.